# Flutter. Is it possible somehow decorate SliverList/SliverGrid?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I need to make a scrollable for all content for partiular page, but the problem is that I need to have dynamic list at the middle, which grows. So I use CustomScrollView. From top to bottom at slivers[] I have SliverToBoxAdapter decorated as I need, then SliverList and then another one SliverToBoxAdapter. This totaly what I need it is scrollable all together, byt decoration problem with SliverList. So i need to wrap somehow SliverList with the same style so it looks like content inside SliverToBoxAdapter (Borders, evevation, background etc). But I cant understand how to achieve this. The CustomScrollView accepts only Slivers..

1. I tried to put List inside SliverToBoxAdapter but it scrolls separately or...
2. Ive solved it but I think in comletely wrong way, with wrapShrink to True, but the Docs day it is very expensive.. And also weird because i moreover need to block scroll Physics  with NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(). So looking for better solution

Maybe I do not need to use Slivers?

The general problem is I need vertically lets say Container then List (growable) and then another Container under the list, no matter how long the list are.

Like this

---

### container

---

### List with ability to
dynamically grow when user
taps button

---

### Container strongly under
the List with button
by tapping which user add
the element to the List

Any solutions, ideas, advices ...
Thanks for attention)

Code for sake of simplicity
The BoxAdapter and SliverList

```
                child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Characteristics(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // this is how I have done
                  // but do not like not lazy.. 
                  // if put SliverList directly cant decorate it.. 
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (contex, index){
                          return Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
                            child: Text('Grid Item $index'),
                          );
                        },
                      itemCount: 20,
                    )
                  ),


                 ],
              ),
```

Comment: can you add some code of what you tried?

Comment: @DineshNagarajan  Thanks I added some code..

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap you Sliver with [DecoratedSliver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DecoratedSliver-class.html), and give it a `BoxDecoration`. This preserves `CustomScrollView`'s property of dynamically building its children.

For example:

```
DecoratedSliver(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  sliver: SliverList.builder(
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text('Child $index'),
    ),
  ),
),
```